# Can I access AppFog services like MySQL from Add-ons?

Tags: paas, appfog

Is it possible to access  AppFog services like the MySQL database from Add-ons?
For example if I want to run some jobs on IronWorker and populate the results in my main App database running on AppFog.
If I check the credentials, it looks like these services are only internal IPs?!

```
Array ( [mysql-5.1] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [name] => dbname [label] => mysql-5.1 [plan] => free [tags] => Array ( [0] => mysql [1] => mysql-5.1 [2] => relational [3] => mysql-5.1 [4] => mysql ) [credentials] => Array ( [name] => d47fb5d7de0024290b53f74466ce00b [hostname] => 10.0.17.107 [host] => 10.0.17.107 [port] => 3306 [user] => uzBFvlo5ciU [username] => uzBFXPo5ciU [password] => p0fSFCOpWKs ) ) ) )
```

Cheers Stefan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it looks like I'm right and it isn't possible for production use.
The AppFog Database services are just configured for internal access.

[1] https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/appfog-users/I31ni0pff9I